# webpackJsonp is not defined getting error while convert less files to one global css file

Tags: angular, webpack, less

I use this as reference link https://blog.angularindepth.com/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client-d4adf15c4975

My webpack.config.js (only changes for less loader )

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const webPack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const extractLess = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].css",
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});

module.exports = {
    entry: ...,

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader" 
                }, {
                    loader: "less-loader"
                }]
            },
        ],
output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: 'chunk/[name].js',
        publicPath: 'dist/',
    },
    }
```

After running command webpack in cmd it will create styles.js 
and after running project i am getting webpackjsonp is not defined ??

I want to load  all less file in one css file 
Thanks in advance